# Using ajax with laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'd like to know if it's possible to use `Ajax` with `Laravel` without writing the code inside a .js file.

#### Script.js

```
$('#selectSemestres').change(function(obj){
        var anoSemestre = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '',
            data: ...

        });
    })
```

I don't know how to get the `URL` that I want (which is my currently page,
I just want to change the < select>  value then reload the data that's already shown on the page).

Do I have to write the ajax inside my `.php` files? Is this a 'good practice'?
I'm asking this because I already have another script inside that same .php file.

**Update**

Following the answer posted by @ohgodwhy
Now nothing happens when the ajax executes.

It hits the `success` code but nothing happens, the  URL does not change. Is it because I'm redirecting to the same page am at?

#### file.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#selectSemestres').change(function(obj){
        var anoSemestre = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{{ route('professor') }}',
            data: { anoSemestre: anoSemestre },
            success: function(){
                console.log('HELLO WORLD');
            }

        });
    })
</script>
```

#### MyController:

```
public function getProfessorList()
    {
        $professor = Professor::all();
        if( Request::ajax() )
        {
            echo 'yolo';
        }
        $semestres = Horario::distinct()->select('ano_semestre')->get()->toArray();
        return View::make('professor', compact('professor', 'semestres'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is add a `@yield('scripts')` section to my layout that I extend.

Then in the child templates that require specific JS, I'll add that in there.

```
@section('scripts')
     <script>
         //your javascript here.
     </script>
@endsection
```

There is 1 caveat however. If you use an `@include` from within a child template, and that `included file` has it's own javascript, it must invoke the parent first, like this:

```
@section('scripts')
    @parent
    <script>

    </script>
@endsection.
```

Comment: So I do have to write it inside the php file, right? I always saw this as a bad practice or something that you should avoid

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro I disagree completely. If you have functionality specific to a given view - yes. Otherwise, if you can *widgetize* it so-to-speak feel free. Don't try to microoptimize your application out of the gate - write the code, get it bug free and functional, push it production. If you start making money, then hire some guys and go for a refactor. It's not a huge deal.

Comment: Followed your suggestion but now I'm getting an error. Any idea?